# pandas dataframe create a new binary activity column based on another file containg a column of names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
                  LigandName    Score
0   _017_model1/_017_model1     -10.54
1   _010_model1/_010_model1     -9.49
2   _113_model1/_113_model1     -9.40
3   _009_model1/_009_model1     -9.37
4   _193_model1/_193_model1     -9.36
```

This is the first few rows of the dataframe. I want to add a new column called IsActive, which is based on the presence of the LigandName in that file. This is the file

```
0   _017_model1/_017_model1
1   _010_model1/_010_model1
2   _113_model1/_113_model1
3   _009_model1/_009_model1
4   _004_model1/_004_model1
```

If the LigandName is present, the IsActive entry should be 1, and 0 if it wasn't. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create boolean mask by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) and cast to integers - `True`s are `1` and `False`s are `0`:

```
print (df1)
                LigandName
0  _017_model1/_017_model1
1  _010_model1/_010_model1
2  _113_model1/_113_model1
3  _009_model1/_009_model1
4  _004_model1/_004_model1

df['IsActive'] = df['LigandName'].isin(df1['LigandName']).astype(int)
print (df)
                LigandName  Score  IsActive
0  _017_model1/_017_model1 -10.54         1
1  _010_model1/_010_model1  -9.49         1
2  _113_model1/_113_model1  -9.40         1
3  _009_model1/_009_model1  -9.37         1
4  _193_model1/_193_model1  -9.36         0
```

Comment: It gives me an error when I try to access the df['LigandName'] for some reason, why does that happen? A key error.

Comment: OK, second file is converted to DataFrame? Like `df1 = pd.read_csv(file, names=['LigandName'])` ?

Comment: That's right as df1 doesn't have the header already, but df has the headers in the file, I didn't add them myself, can that be the problem? Should I remove the headers from the file, and then add them myself? And if that is the solution, how can I do that?

Comment: @AhmedSamir - If second file have no header, then is added to DataFrame lik ecolumn name by parameter `names`. If have header use `df1 = pd.read_csv(file)` and check `print (df1.columns)` for change solution like `df['IsActive'] = df['LigandName'].isin(df1['column of file']).astype(int)`